# How to merge two excel files that has different table headings into one master file via python?

Tags: python, excel

I have different excel sheets that has almost identical table headings but the orders are different. I would like to order them in the same format and merge those files via python.

Answer (score 0):

Use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html), would be something like that :

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

classeur1 = load_workbook('test1.xlsx')
classeur2 = load_workbook('test2.xlsx')
feuille1 = classeur1.active
feuille2 = classeur2.active

workbook_result = Workbook()
f_result = workbook_result.active

for row in feuille1.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        f_result.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column).value = cell.value

for row in feuille2.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if f_result.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column).value:
            f_result.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column).value += cell.value
        else:
            f_result.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column)

workbook_result.save('merged.xlsx')
```

maybe it will be so much different, it depends on data